# Get image name after picking image from Camera through UIImagepickerController and saving it to photos album in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, ios9

I saved image to the Camera Roll with the function...

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imurl!,nil,nil,nil)

How to get the name or URL of the saved image with function ??

Comment: please show your snap code that you try in your project

Answer (score 1):

You can use ALAssetsLibrary framework to save image on disk.

Please try following method -

```
ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(editedImage.CGImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: editedImage.imageOrientation.rawValue)!,
            completionBlock:{ (path:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                print("Image path - \(path)")
        })
```

Comment: No actually  this is depreceated in ios 9.0

Comment: New solution for you @SaikrishnaBurra https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-how-to-write-to-the-ios-photo-album

Comment: No bro ...this didnt help me out....after completion of saving how to get the image name?

Answer (score 0):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

          let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
          // here you got file path that you select from camera roll

          let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
         // here you got image that select from camera roll now just save it

         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Comment: im getting the imageUrl as nil , thanks. Any other way?

Comment: are you sure that you are getting nil because i never get it nil this code i already using in my current app.

Comment: yes i'm getting nil.......checked it again...did you save the image to photo albums?

Comment: now i m not save image to photo album but i save image in filemanager and just access it for chat view . i just save url of image and save it in document directory

Comment: How to save the image in document directory?

Comment: Did u provide the image name by yourselves(custom name) before saving?